# Eclipse Plugin Dev - How to get running Java applications?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I'm new to Eclipse plugin development.
I'm trying to find a way to get information about what Java applications are running at the moment, and which configuration they were launched from.

How am I able to get this information?

Edit: I'm not looking for how to create a launch configuration, but rather see what applications are already running, launched through Eclipse.  Basically, what configurations have been launched, and are still running through Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ILaunchManager.getProcesses()` to get the list of running processes that the launch manager knows about:

```
ILaunchManager manager = DebugPlugin.getLaunchManager();

IProcess [] processes = manager.getProcesses();
```